# Debugging 2 nodemon instances with VS Code on different ports

Tags: visual-studio-code, nodemon, vscode-debugger

I am currently developing an app entirely with Node.js, and have therefore 2 nodemon instances running at the same time, the `client` and the `server`:

```
.
|-- README.md
|-- client
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- node_modules
|   |-- package-lock.json
|   `-- package.json
`-- server
    |-- index.js
    |-- node_modules
    |-- package-lock.json
    `-- package.json

4 directories, 7 files
```

So this is the opened directory in VS Code. In the `scripts` section of both `package.json` I have the following : 
`"dev": "nodemon --inspect ./index.js"`

I made some research on how to debug a nodemon instance, and I found this configuration on VS Code's repository :

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Node: Nodemon",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "restart": true,
        "protocol": "inspector",
    }
]
```

But now the problem is, when I run the two scripts at the same time, I have the following error in my terminal : `Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use`

Is it possible to use the debugger on another port ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--inspect=<port>` to specify which port the debugger should run.

Example:

For Client app, to run on default port for debugger (i.e, 9229) -

```
"dev": "nodemon --inspect ./index.js"
```

For Server app, to run debugger on port 9228 -

```
"dev": "nodemon --inspect=9228 ./index.js"
```